# In WebStorm, how to show all changes on a git branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm

I use WebStorm.

I make a new git branch, and make changes, committing each time. Lets say I now have 5 commits on my new branch.

Within WebStorm, I can see each commit, and the diff in each of those commits.

How can I see all the changes in a single diff between the top of my branch and the original branch. For example, if I were to make a PR on GitHub, I would see this diff.

I don't want to squash my commits yet.